# call to shellexecte causes antivirus to give a warning?

Tags: delphi, winapi, shellexecute

when ever i write the following line of code any where in any app i program with delphi

```
ShellExecute(self.WindowHandle,'open','www.yahoo.com',nil,nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

kaspersky 2010 beeps this message
''behavior similar to pdm.hidden data sending. detected''

why is that and how do i get rid of this

note: i am using delphi 2007

**update :sorry for not clearifing, when ever i RUN my program av gives me this error**

Comment: Do you also get the warning when you replace 'www.yahoo.com' with 'notepad.exe'? If so, than it is not the URL that gives problems.

Comment: no The_Fox i have opened notepad without any problems its just the url(any url) that gives problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Send your application to Kaspersky lab, marking your request with "false-positive" comment.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be issue in Kaspersky Internet Security 2011 number 94754.
Updating software may help.

Answer (score 1):

Kaspersky probably detects that you want to open an URL, which could of course be something like www.example.com/submit.php?stolencreditcardnumber=12345 and gives the message. Maybe you can get rid of it by not using a constant string for the URL but assign the URL at run-time, so Kaspersky does not detect the opening of a URL.

```
ShellExecute(self.WindowHandle, 'open', MyURL, nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

This is of course just guessing.

Comment: AV still gives the same warning

Answer (score 1):

I Shell Execute URIs all the time, don't get any problems with AV software (see EasyBCD for an example software of mine that does this). So it could be that Kaspersky detects the combination of both the Delphi framework + the URI ShellExecute code as the problem. Delphi is not an uncommon malware language.

One thing you can try: Run "iexplore.exe" with MyUrl as a command-line argument.

Comment: I'd avoid running directly iexplore.exe, since, as stated in another comment, AFAIK it isn't guaranteed to be in the path, and - most important - in that way you are ignoring user preferences about the default browser.