# How do you go to a web page without causing an AV false alarm?

Tags: url, alarm, launch, antivirus

I'm writing a Winforms app in C# which takes a little input from the user and appends it to the end of a hard-coded URL for a particular web site. Then my program passes the resulting string to Process.Start like so:
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fullURL)

This has the effect of doing a search for the user's string on the web site.

Whenever that line of code gets executed, Kaspersky antivirus gives a warning about behavior similar to "PDM.Hidden Data sending".  If and when I distribute this program to other people, I don't want them to be nervous about the possibility that I've given them some kind of malware.  Is there some way to browse to a dynamically built URL without making AV programs like Kaspersky raise unnecessary warnings like this?

In this thread: [call to shellexecte causes antivirus to give a warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872256/call-to-shellexecte-causes-antivirus-to-give-a-warning)
... I noticed an interesting tip about sending the app to Kaspersky with a "false-positive" comment.  But I'm really hoping for a code-based solution that would avoid the need to do that. After all it is pretty common for the help systems of some applications to take you to their maker's web site. How do you suppose they do that without causing false alarms??

Thanks,

Larry

Comment: If there were a good method of doing it without triggering the malware warning then the malware authors would use that method instead. Then it would get added as a malware warning!

Answer (score 0):

Would it be acceptable for your users if you loaded the page using a WebBrowser control within your winforms app?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx

Comment: That's certainly a lot better than a false AV alarm, but I'd prefer to use an existing browser, if not the user's default browser so as not to give the false impression the web site is "in" my app. I anticpate very non-technical users.